# dbt - select from model itself / how to transform this query?

Tags: sql, dbt

I have a model, which "merges" data in a table. If the unique key (song_id) already exists, I will update the last_loaded column. If however last_loaded from the sink table is older than 1 day, I will also update the first loaded column, else it should just update last_loaded.
The problem is, with my solution I have to reference the model in itself, which does not work in dbt. Has somebody else maybe got a solution for this?
This is the config for my current model:

```
{{config(materialized='incremental',unique_key='song_id',merge_update_columns = ['last_loaded', 'first_loaded'],schema = "mart")}}
```

The original query in redshift looks like this:

```
WITH fact_intermediate AS(
SELECT
st.song_id,
st.album_id,
st.artist_id,
d1.date_id as first_loaded,
d1.date_id as last_loaded,
st.song_duration_ms
FROM stage.stg_chart_songs st
INNER JOIN mart.dim_dates d1 ON current_date = d1.year || '-' || d1.month || '-' || d1.day)

SELECT
fi.song_id,
fi.artist_id,
fi.album_id,
CASE
WHEN current_date - TO_DATE(fc.last_loaded, 'yyyy-mm-dd') > 1 THEN current_date::varchar
ELSE fc.first_loaded
END AS first_loaded,
CURRENT_DATE AS last_loaded
FROM fact_intermediate fi
left outer join mart.fact_charts fc ON fi.song_id = fc.song_id;
```

I am absolutely no expert with sql and dbt, has someone maybe got a idea how to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `{{ this }}` variable which lets you avoid circular references ([source](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/this)).